# How to change NEXT iFrame src on link click with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to change the next iframe's src when a link targeted by a class is clicked.

The html structure is

```
<a class="link"></a>
<div>
   <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

I will have multiple of these on the page so I want to make sure it uses class, and .next() so that it will work on any on the instances.

I had this

```
$('.showLink').click(function(e){
    $(this).next('iframe').attr("src", "LINK GOES HERE");
});
```

Comment: `$(this).next('div>iframe')`

Answer (score 1):

The `iframe` element is not a `sibling` of the `a`, so `next` is not going to work in that manner. You need to use `next()` to get the `div`, then `find` the `iframe` within that:

```
$('.showLink').click(function(e){
    $(this).next('div').find('iframe').attr("src", "LINK GOES HERE");
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k5oryfeq/)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector has problems because the element next to the link is not an `iframe` but a `div` that contains the `iframe`.

`$(this).next('iframe')` would work if `iframe` was just next to the link.

You should use this as your selector: `$(this).next('div').children('iframe')`

Comment: Note that the descendant selector doesn't work when using any of jQuery's sibling methods: http://jsfiddle.net/LbqayLh5/

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.showLink').click(function(e){
   $(this).closest('iframe').attr("src", "LINK GOES HERE");
});
```

Comment: $(this).next('div').closest('iframe').attr("src", "LINK GOES HERE");

Comment: That still won't work. It should be `.find('iframe')` not `.closest('iframe')`.